Emgu.CV QueryFrame Function Error: 'OpenCV: _step >= minstep' On changing Resolution
I'm Working on Image Processing With Emgu.CV (4.9.0.5494).
all things were ok until I tried to change the capture resolution:
_capture.Start();
_captureInProgress = true;
await Task.Delay(500);
_capture.Set(CapProp.FrameWidth, 1280);
_capture.Set(CapProp.FrameHeight, 720);
_capture.Set(CapProp.Fps, 30);
_capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

after change resolution i Got this: 'OpenCV: _step >= minstep' On _capture.QueryFrame()
when I remove these lines, everything will be OK: (default resolution is 640*480)
_capture.Set(CapProp.FrameWidth, 1280);
_capture.Set(CapProp.FrameHeight, 720);
_capture.Set(CapProp.Fps, 30);

I attached a picture of debugging too.
what should I do?
thanks.


You didn't show all the relevant code (with the actual opencv calls for capture), but anyway if you don't succeed to change the capture size, you can capture with default size, and then use the C# equivalent of cv::resize to change the frame size.

in this case, I lost the capture quality, if I got 640480 and changed to 1280720. am I wrong?

You could be right, if the camera supports the higher resolution. This is why I wrote "if you don't succeed to change the capture size". Anyway - please post all the relevant code in a form of a [mre] (specifically the opencv capture code).

I have not used OpenCVs video capture, but I have used several other camera libraries. Changing resolution while capturing is often not possible, since the backend uses a pool of fixed sized buffers. So anything that changes the size of images typically require capture to be stopped first, so the buffers can be cleaned up and re-allocated in a controlled manner.

Yes, quality will suffer to some extent when you increase the image size. The algorithm has to fill in the area between the existing pixels.

I found the Solution!
I'm trying to set VideoCapture parameters instead of using Set Functions in Constructor. like this:
and everything works fine!
   Tuple<CapProp, int>[] prop = new Tuple<CapProp, int>[3];
   prop[0] = new Tuple<CapProp, int>(CapProp.FrameWidth, 2560);
   prop[1] = new Tuple<CapProp, int>(CapProp.FrameHeight, 1440);
   prop[2] = new Tuple<CapProp, int>(CapProp.Fps, 30);
   _capture = new VideoCapture(1, VideoCapture.API.Any, prop);

